# Placing a trait on the field of a stuct

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and I'm building an Adapter struct that has a cache to store fetched data locally. I had it working successfully for a `HashMap` but wanted to generalize it to let users swap this out for any other type that implements my `Cache` Trait.

How can I refactor this to an interface-like implementation?

```
pub trait Cache {
    fn insert(&mut self, data: Budgets) -> anyhow::Result<()>;
}

// #[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Adapter<'a, T: Cache> {
    base_uri: &'a str,
    client: reqwest::blocking::Client,
    default_budget: Option<&'a str>,
    //cache: HashMap<String, Budget>  <-- original impl
    //cache: &'a dyn Cache  <-- Not sure how to make this work
    cache: T
}
```

I was able to get a hacky solution working where I used the above uncommented code and then created a new struct for my trait:

```
pub struct HashCache {
    cache: HashMap<String, Budget>
}

impl Cache for HashCache {
    fn insert(&mut self, data: Budgets) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
        for budget in data.budgets.into_iter() {
            self.cache.insert(budget.name.clone(), budget);
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

This then required me to make a dirty `new` method requiring a concrete type parameter:

```
impl<'a> Adapter<'a,  HashCache> {
    pub fn new(bearer: String) -> Self {
       // -- other fields --
            //cache: HashMap::new()
            cache: HashCache { cache: HashMap::new() }
        }
    }
```

And now that I have to go through a struct, traversing the cache has an extra issue:

```
    pub fn show_accounts(&self, budget_name: &str) {
        if let Some(b) = self.cache.cache.get(budget_name) {  <-- Requires getting into the struct
            if let Some(a) = &b.accounts {
                println!("{:?}", a)
            } else {
                println!{"No accounts present"}
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you define `Cache` in your crate, it should be possible to directly implement the trait on HashMap:

```rust
impl Cache for HashMap<String, Budget> {
    // ...
}
```

To avoid the "dirty new method" problem, you could also require that the type implement `Default`, so you could write e.g.

```rust
impl<'a, T: Cache + Default> Adapter<'a, T> {
    pub fn new(bearer: String) -> Self {
            // -- other fields --
            cache: T::default()
        }
    }
}
```

In the case of `show_accounts()`, since you're using a generic `T`, you shouldn't hardcode HashMap methods. Instead, add those methods to the `Cache` trait:

```rust
pub trait Cache {
    fn get(s: String) -> Option<Budget>;
    fn insert(&mut self, data: Budgets) -> anyhow::Result<()>;
    // -- other methods --
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware I could implement custom traits on default types.

Comment: @SeveMartinez yep! The key term here is "foreign." You can implement foreign traits on your own types and you can implement your own traits on foreign types, but you may not implement a foreign trait on a foreign type.